# Running a javascript file with imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I've inherited somebody else's mess and am not sure where to begin.
I have imacros7 desktop version and a js file, and was told to 'run it'

From what i gather i should also have a iim file to run the macro or at least have access to imacro from a browser window (it says firefox is not compatible).

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need a mozilla firefox browser , install imacros , create a javascript file wth imacro code and js code and that will be good to go.

chrome supports only iim file for imacros. upgrade ur browser and test again.